# how to extract data to array value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, highcharts

```
$match = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')
->selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
->orderBy("date")
->groupBy("date")
->get() // return result set (collection) from query builder
->pluck('cnt') // only need the cnt column
->values() // array_values
->all(); // convert collection to array
```

using the code above i get the output in my view like:
[image]

but i have to change my code a bit to get another date value and when i did that with my code

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->get();
// $array[] = [];
foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $day = substr($match->date_access, 0, 10);
    if(isset($array[$day]))
    {
      $array[$day]++;
    } else 
    {
      $array[$day] = 1;
    }
    $match = $array;
}
```

now im getting output in my views like:
[image]

now how can i make them into an array? for example it should be ["2018-03-04", 3] and so on with the following date and value.. how can i do that? the reason im doing this is because with the first way it works when i insert the values to view on highcharts but with the second it doesnt view

Comment: Use `toArray()` or `json_decode()` to convert resource collection to a PHP array. Then loop through the array and process the string as per the required format.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's collection method [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-transform) to transform the collection results. And then convert the collection to an array.

Something like this:

```
$match = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')
    ->selectRaw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(1) as cnt') // created_at here is datetime format, only need the date portion using `DATE` function
    ->orderBy("date")
    ->groupBy("date")
    ->get(); // return result set (collection) from query builder

$match = $match->transform(function($item) {
    return [
        substr($item->date, 0, 10),
        $item->cnt,
    ];
})->toArray()
```